# derivation function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want actually undestand what is happening in this code. Can someone tell me what it's the main idea. I get that is derivation of a polynom. But I don't know what `derN xs 1 , derN xs (n+1) and derN xs 0` actually do

```
derN :: P -> Int -> P
derN [] n = []


derPolinom :: P -> P
derPolinom xs = derN xs 0
```

Comment: The second argument of `derN` seems to be keeping track of the degree of the "current" term, so as we chomp along the list, we increment the degree.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help to work through an example. It looks like you have a definition like `type P = [Int]`, so I’ll assume that. Let’s take the polynomial 3x<sup>2</sup> + 5x + 7, which would be represented in this scheme as `[7, 5, 3]`.

To compute the derivative of this polynomial, we start with `derPolynom`:

```
derPolinom [7, 5, 3]
=
derN [7, 5, 3] 0
```

So we just call `derN`. We find the first case that matches:

```
derN (x:xs) 0 = derN xs 1
```

Then `x` is `7` and `xs` is `[5, 3]`, so we substitute those values into the body:

```
derN [5, 3] 1
```

We’ve arrived at another call, so we find the case that matches:

```
derN (x:xs) n = [n * x] ++ derN xs (n+1)
```

This time, `x` is `5`, `xs` is `[3]`, and `n` is `1`. Again substitute:

```
[1 * 5] ++ derN [3] (1 + 1)
=
[5] ++ derN [3] 2
```

Now we have another recursive call, which matches the same pattern, binding `x` = `3`, `xs` = `[]`, and `n` = `2`:

```
[5] ++ ([2 * 3] ++ derN [] (2 + 1))
[5] ++ ([6] ++ derN [] 3)
```

Finally we’ve reached the base case of the recursion:

```
derN [] n = []
```

So we perform our last substitution:

```
[5] ++ ([6] ++ [])
```

Then reduce to get an answer of `[5, 6]`, which represents the polynomial 6x + 5, which is indeed the derivative of 3x<sup>2</sup> + 5x + 7.

You’ll notice that we’re only ever prepending single-element lists, so this line:

```
derN (x:xs) n = [n * x] ++ derN xs (n+1)
```

Could be simplified into this:

```
derN (x:xs) n = n * x : derN xs (n+1)
```

This whole function could also be written more simply using a higher-order function to avoid having to write out the recursion explicitly. We can use `drop` to remove the last coefficient and `zipWith (*) [1..]` to multiply each remaining number in the list by its 1-based index (which indicates the exponent).

```
derPolinom xs = zipWith (*) [1..] (drop 1 xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are recursive calls. For instance, `derN (x:xs) 0 = derN xs 1` should be read as "The derivative of a polynom, with `x` as a free member and `xs` as other coefficients, is the same as derivative of a polynom with coefficients `xs`, starting with power 1".

This procedure takes the list of coefficients of a polynom and builds the list of coefficients of its derivative, recursively traversing from the lowest power to the highest.